# 27-inch iMac on a wobbly floor

Tags: imac

I have set my 27-inch iMac on a desk on a wobbly floor with a thick carpet. When people walk in the room, the desk tends to shake, and so does the iMac.

I worry that the joint between the iMac and its integrated stand might be damaged due to the vibration. Could this be a problem?

Comment: I think the mount will be fine, your hard drive on the other hand could suffer more if the shaking is real bad.

Comment: I would look to level/stabilize the desk as the first step. Chase causes, not symptoms.

Comment: I agree with @Gerry although doesn't iMac also have the hdd fail save included that is in the laptops of apple? ( which pulls the read/write 'pin' in the hard drive to the side upon movement )

Answer (score 1):

If your wall is more stable you could always get a [wall mount](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD179ZM/A) for it. They cost around $30-$40 on Apple's site. For the money it would be worth a try, or move the iMac somewhere sturdier in your house possibly. If the integrated mount were to somehow fail, the shag carpet might help minimize any resulting damage.

Answer (score 1):

No. That stand is, in typical Apple fashion, over-engineered. If you are tired of getting sea-sickness watching a wobbly screen, mount it to the wall using a third party wall mounting kit (VESA adapter for the Mac, a VESA mount for the wall), or secure the desk to the wall with some screws and drywall anchors.

Comment: I'll second this - I've seen iMacs mounted to vehicles and ships that go through rolls and bumps more than would tip the iMac off any table were it not secured. The hinges are very strong, work in any orientation and would need an acceleration like a fall from more than 6 inches to think about causing issues to the hinge mechanism. Now the HD or other things might not like jostles. As long as you're not concerned it will tip over, you can rest easy on the hinge having a problem in your iMac.